# Primefaces Schedule: How to block times?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, schedule

I want to use the primefaces schedule component to display some sort of calendar.
The user to should be able to create and edit apointments which all works fine.

One thing I couldn´t achieve was to create "blocked" dates :

At certain times (say for lunch break) I do not want anybody to be able to create appointments there. I would like to have it visualized in some way, with a different color or so.

One way that I don´t think it will work is to add "Blocked Events" (represent lunch break with an own event), because then Drag and Drop would also affect those events. While maybe it is technically possible to prevent those events from being moved, I really would like to find another approach.

Who knows how to add blocked dates (lunch break, weekends etc) ?

Comment: have you got any solution for this problem?

Comment: now my problem is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553901/how-to-disable-specifice-date-time-and-all-friday-or-any-day-in-primefaces-sched

Answer (score 0):

You can send a DefaulScheduleEvent to set your start and end date:

http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/model/DefaultScheduleEvent.html

Check a example here:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml